# How can I have multible "INLINE" subreports growing in different sheet in (Pentaho report designer 5.0)?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, pentaho

Everything works perfectly in "Banded" mode, I can crate N number of sub reports which result's in different sheets .
But I'm not able to create multiple sub-reports in **INLINE** mode ,**its displaying all those reports in 1'ST SUB-REPORT,** (i.e,  MASTER REPORT which is displaying its own data in sheet0 AND 1ST-SUBREPORT which is playing 1st-subreports content, as well as other sub-reports contents in SHEET1 (BUT NOT IN SEPARATE SHEET )......
what settings should i do in **page behaviour section** ????
THANK-YOU

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach that does produce some results, though not perfect, is creating yet another level of sub-reports:

Level 1 - the master report, with several banded sub-reports, one for each line of sub-report components you want.

Level 2 - the banded sub-reports. Each with multiple children sub-reports, inline, one for each column of content;

Level 3 - the content sub-reports.

As content grows on Level 3, it will overlap elements on level 2, but (please check this works everytime) should not overlap on level 1 as level 2 sub-reports are banded and will grow automatically.

This approach is most likely heavily dependent on the Pentaho Report Designer version you use.